# Django render template from media folder

Tags: django, templates, renderer

I'm trying to provide additional level of flexibility for some views, specifically, I want to be able to render a view using a django template from the media location (say referred to by a FileField, but it shouldn't matter).

What's the best way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that directory to [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-template-dirs-setting) setting, and then use appropriate template name or path in view.

Templates in django can reside anywhere on filesystem.